# PostgreSQL 9.4 hangs during installation at "Removing obsolete dictionary files:"

Tags: apt, postgresql

Good day.

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on an Ubuntu server (15.04) 64 bit.  I checked/updated the sources.list and ran:

```
# apt-get update
```

followed by:

```
# apt-get install postgresql
```

The installation started until it came to "Removing obsolete dictionary files:" where it hangs:

```
# apt-get install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql-9.4 postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc oidentd ident-server locales-all postgresql-doc-9.4 openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql postgresql-9.4 postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,934 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid-updates/main libpq5 amd64 9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04 [77.5 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid/main postgresql-client-common all 166bzr2 [26.9 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid-updates/main postgresql-client-9.4 amd64 9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04 [817 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid/main ssl-cert all 1.0.35 [17.4 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid/main postgresql-common all 166bzr2 [151 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid-updates/main postgresql-9.4 amd64 9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04 [2,839 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages/ vivid/main postgresql all 9.4+166bzr2 [5,104 B]
Fetched 3,934 kB in 0s (14.4 MB/s)     
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 57554 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpq5_9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq5:amd64 (9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-common.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-common_166bzr2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-common (166bzr2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-9.4.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-9.4_9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-9.4 (9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ssl-cert.
Preparing to unpack .../ssl-cert_1.0.35_all.deb ...
Unpacking ssl-cert (1.0.35) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-common_166bzr2_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Unpacking postgresql-common (166bzr2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-9.4.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-9.4_9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-9.4 (9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_9.4+166bzr2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (9.4+166bzr2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up libpq5:amd64 (9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (166bzr2) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-9.4 (9.4.2-0ubuntu0.15.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/man/man1/psql.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/psql.1.gz (psql.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.35) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (166bzr2) ...
Adding user postgres to group ssl-cert

Creating config file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/logrotate.d/postgresql-common with new version
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
```

I left it, but quit after a while.  After getting rid of the locks, I tried running:

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

which continued and got stuck at exactly the same place ("Removing obsolete...).

It seems to be something to do with "aspell", but I have no idea what exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried changing the locale and got this:

```
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
# LANG=POSIX
# apt-get install postgresql
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up postgresql-common (166bzr2) ...
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_gb
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
```

Comment: What is  that Place!! How could we help if we don't know what really happened? please add the list of errors and the place that stuck in to your question above

Comment: @Maythux No need to get annoyed... :-( As my post says, there was no errors.  The process hangs at "Removing obsolete dictionary files:".

Comment: I'm not annoyed I'm just telling you that you'll never get help with this question, you have to specify the steps and the errors you faced

Comment: Moving to Ubuntu 14 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install it on a docker container and everything works fine. Maybe this is caused by your locale. You can check it with the command: `locale`.
You can try to change it temporarily typing: `LANG=POSIX` and then retry to install postgresql in the same terminal.

Comment: Does not seem to be working... I've updated the question with the result.

Comment: I moved to Ubuntu 14 LTS and that solved the issue.  It completed without any glitches.